# VSTS Release AzureRM Powershell Version

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-devops

I'm building a extension for VSTS that uses the AzureRM module. On every load we see that the 2.1.0 version gets loaded in a release pipeline in a Hosted agent. To load the AzureRM module we use the module: VstsAzureHelpers_

In that version there seem to be a bug, on some operation we receive the following exception: Exception of type 'Microsoft.Rest.Azure.CloudException' was thrown.
on for example this operation: New-AzureRmRoleAssignment

Comment: try using a newer versión of pipeline agent. say vs2017 one

Comment: Already tried that and it is currently using: Hosted VS2017

Comment: i never had any problems with that.

Comment: Just try the operations and you will see the cloud exception.

Answer (score 0):

With latest [VstsAzureHelpers](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/tree/master/Tasks/Common/VstsAzureHelpers_), it adds `azurePsVersion` parameter that used to specify the module version, such as 5.1.1.

Snip code:

```
function Initialize-Azure {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param( [string] $azurePsVersion )

function Import-AzureModule {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [ValidateSet('Azure', 'AzureRM')]
        [string[]] $PreferredModule,
        [string] $azurePsVersion)
```

I recommend that you can refer to [AzurePowerShell](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/AzurePowerShell/AzurePowerShell.ps1) task (2.*) to update your extension code.